# MySQL: Add an identifying field to UNION queries

Tags: mysql, union

If I have a MySQL query that contains a union, is there a way to add a custom field to each record in my result set that identifies which query that record is a result of?

So if my result set was generated from the records returned by two queries merged together by a union, the last field of each record row would be 'type' and either have a value of 'query1' or 'query2'.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking for something like this?

```
select 'query1' as type, a, b, c, d from table1
union 
select 'query2' as type, a, b, c, d from table2
```